# How do I cleanly and conflict-free revert all changes made to a repository from a given point forwards? Things are on fire and I'm in a hurry

Tags: git

The repository was at commit A and things were okay. I pushed things, moving origin/HEAD to commit B, and things are now on fire.

How do I git push a revert all the way to commit A in a hurry, so that I can put the fires out first and ask question later?

Comment: Asking for a friend.

Answer (score 1):

`git revert` might be the best option. If you only have one commit that you want to roll back then you can do this:

```
git revert B
git push
```

Typically you should never attempt to re-write history in a shared repository. All pushes should be "fast-forward". Using `git revert`  will create a commit that undoes the changes in `B`. You are now effectively back at commit `A`, but you've rolled forward rather than trying to roll back.

You can come back later to un-revert the changes in `B` (by running `git revert` again) and fix whatever started your fires.

If you have more than one commit to revert then you can specify them all: `git revert B C D`, or you might be able to use `git revert A..HEAD` (I haven't tested that syntax).

Your history will look like this once you've done the first revert

`A -> B -> revert "B"`

Some time later, once you've fixed all the problems, it might look like this:

`A -> B -> revert "B" -> revert "revert "B"" -> fix B's problems`

Comment: I want to upvote this because this was my _friend's_ first approach. Unfortunately in my— their case git revert was giving me merge conflicts even after specifying `--strategy=ours`. Somehow the things git struggles the hardest with are README files with change logs

Comment: Weird. Have you tried 'git reset --hard B; git revert B'?

Comment: For a single commit that should do it indeed, I was reverting six or so

Comment: It should still work...just run `git reset --hard G; git revert B C D E F G`

Comment: Or revert them one-by-one in reverse order. It's possible that when it tries to create one big revert commit it runs into merge conflicts. One-by-one reverts should avoid that problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
git stash
git fetch
git reset --hard $known_good_commit_A
git reset --soft origin/HEAD
git commit -m 'Emergency revert, things are on fire'
git push
```

Say this is your repo history: (WD = working directory)

```
A (known-good) → ... → B (HEAD, WD, origin/HEAD, things-on-fire)
```

The first reset changes your working directory to A, discarding all changes.

```
A (WD, HEAD, known-good) → ... → B (origin/HEAD, things-on-fire)
```

The second reset merely moves head back to B.

```
A (WD, known-good) → ... → B (HEAD, origin/HEAD, things-on-fire)
```

Your revert is now already staged and ready to commit and push, in a conflict-free fashion.

```
A (known-good) → ... → B (things-on-fire) → A' (HEAD, WD, origin/HEAD, emergency)
```

Now you can stop fighting git and start fighting the fire. When things have died down, merely `git revert HEAD; git stash apply` to go back to B and your working directory, so you can remove the source of fires.

---

#### Backout strategies

...for when attempting to put a fire off sets additional things on fire

- `git stash` fails

  - Ignore. If you really have important uncommitted changes, `cd /tmp`, reclone, retry
- `git fetch` fails

  - If you have to push your changes, you'll have to fix this one. Otherwise, ignore.
- `git reset` fails

  - Your repository is on fire, too. `cd /tmp`, reclone, retry.
- `git commit` fails, suggests --allow-empty

  - You screwed up. `git reset --hard origin/HEAD` and try again
- `git commit` fails, suggests fixing conflicts with git-add

  - Your repo might be on fire, `cd /tmp`, reclone, retry. If you still have trouble, I have failed you. Sorry
- `git push` fails

  - If you don't have to push to put off your fire, you can ignore this (you could have stopped at `git reset --hard`)
  - If you could `git fetch` then you probably got beaten to the push by somebody else. Start over.
- Nothing here failed, but the fire only got bigger

  - git won't help you solve the issue, it's time to escalate and get your friendly local sysadmin friends involved. You can undo your revert with `git revert HEAD`

Comment: (This is not standard operating procedure at my company. Please think about your rollback strategy when writing your own custom bash scripts that deal with deployments and the such.)